# How to get object having constructor as other object in spring?

Tags: c#, .net, spring

I am integrating my .net application with Spring. I have trouble with getting Object with having constructor object.

My Object patterns are like:

```
  public class Bar 
  {
     private Foo foo;   

     public void setFoo(Foo foo)
     {
        this.foo = foo;
     }
     public String toString()
     {
       return "Bar! Foo : \n" + foo;  
     }
  }

  public class Foo
  {
     string Id { get; set; }
     string Name { get; set; }
  }
```

My Old C# code:

```
   Foo foo1 = new Foo();
   foo1.Id = 1;
   foo1.Name= "Object 1, Foo1";

   Foo foo2 = new Foo();
   foo2.Id = 2;
   foo2.Name= "Object 2, Foo2";

   Bar b1 = new Bar(foo1);
   Bar b2 = new Bar(foo2);
```

Like without constructor I am using:

```
   Bar bar = (Bar)ContextRegistry.GetContext().GetObject("Bar");
```

I have searched on net and found that need to add foo in XML but I can't do that as it is dynamic per call.

I know spring configuration and here it is:
In my Spring.config\

```
    <object id="Bar" type="NameSpace.Bar, ProjectName" singleton="false">
       <constructor-arg ref="foo"/>
    </object>

    <object id="foo" type="NameSpace.foo, ProjectName" singleton="false">
    </object>
```